# cannot catch htmldocument load exception

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling, try-catch, dom

Sometimes htmlDocument.Load(url) gives me this exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transpo
rt connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. --
```

Unfortunately, i cannot catch this exception.

I catch the exception as following:

```
try
{
   page = web.Load(url + Convert.ToString(i + 1) + "/");
}
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
  //do something
}
```

When I run the program, the exception still stops the program at the line where is written:

```
page = web.Load(url + Convert.ToString(i + 1) + "/");
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the exception thrown is a `System.IO.IOException`, and you are catching an `ArgumentException`.

Change your code to:

```
try
{
   page = web.Load(url + Convert.ToString(i + 1) + "/");
}
catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
{
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just offering another solution. Your catch is for an `ArgumentException` and will catch *only* `ArgumentException`s... what is bring thrown is an `IOException`.

You can change your code to the following if you simply want to catch *all* exceptions thrown by your try block:

```
try
{
   page = web.Load(url + Convert.ToString(i + 1) + "/");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //do something
}
```

If you want to do something different for each exception:

```
try
{
   page = web.Load(url + Convert.ToString(i + 1) + "/");
}
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    //do something about ArgumentException
}
catch (System.IO.IOException ex) 
{
    //do something about IOException
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code catches `ArgumentException`s only.

If you want to catch other kinds of exceptions, you'll need to change that.